# Tener el control de un StatusStrip que pertenece a un Form1 desde Form2 C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, interfaz-gráfica

Tengo un `Form` principal que contiene una barra de estado `StatusStrip` con varios `StatusLabel`. Debo tener el control del `StatusStrip` desde otro formulario para cambiar el mensaje de los `StatusLabel` según lo que esté haciendo.

Por ejemplo si pongo el foco en un textbox del `Form2`, el mensaje debe cambiar en un `StatusLabel`.

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas tener acceso al control del otro formulario si puedes comunicar estos de forma desacoplada usando `interface`

[Comunicar Formularios](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2014/05/comunicar-formularios.html)

En el artículo explico como podrias hacerlo, pero basicamente define una interface

```
interface IFormState{
  void SetState(string msg);
}
```

entonces implemetas esta en el form pricipal

```
public class FormPrincipal : Form, IFormState{

   //aqui implementas la interface

   public button1_Click(..){
         FormHijo frm = new FormHijo(this);
         frm.Show();
   }

}
```

desde el form hijo podrias invocar este metodo definido en la interfaz si tienes la instancia del form principal

```
public class FormHijo : Form{

    private IFormState _frm;

    public FormHijo(IFormState frm){ 
       _frm = frm;
    }

     public button1_Click(..){
        _frm.SetState("mensaje");
     }
}
```

Al pasarle en el costructor podrias tener la instancia del form principal que implemementa la interface.

De esta forma puedes enviar un dato al form principal sin tener que acceder al control del form.

Comment: Hola, he realizado mil y un proceso diferente y nada, cuando creo el objeto del Form1 y voy a utilizar los elementos de el da error.                private void txbvalor_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Principal prin = new Principal();
            prin.StatusMensaje.text = "Debe cambiar el mensaje";
        }                                                                                                                                    "El error aparece en StatusMensaje, me dice que No es acesible debido a su nivel de proteccion"

Comment: pero no tiene que crear ningun objeto Form1. Si usas el new para crear el  Principal esa es una nueva instancia, y tu tienes que usar la existente, es por eso que se usa la interface. Sigue el articulo que recomiendo alli explico con mas detalle como debs hacerlo